# How to convert DetailsView columns to uppercase

Tags: asp.net, string, case

I need to be able to convert all input fields in a DetailsView (Insert) to uppercase. How do I do this? My SQL query and the whole insert statement takes place in ASP.NET, and not in code behind so I'm not sure if I can dynamically do this in ASP.

I've used Text-Transform in CSS to make them *look* uppercase for the user, but it still enters the details in lower case in the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done a cheeky work around - the SQL query simply converts everything to upper case now.